# Как сделать тест для формы /login?

Tags: php, laravel, юнит-тесты

Подскажите, как сделать тест формы `/login`, чтобы можно было заполнить из теста поля формы и проверить с помощью `$this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);`?
Такой вариант не подходит, т.к. тут не вводятся поля в форму.

```
$user = factory(User::class)->states('guest')->create();
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('dashboard');
$response->assert5tatus(401); // Не авторизован
```

**P.S.**
получилось так:

```
    $user = User::find(1);

    $this->post(route('login'), [
        'email' => 'admin@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'ghsgdsfgfg',
    ]);
    $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);
```

можете подсказать по этому вопросу, они связанные? [Testing: Target class [config] does not exist](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142632/testing-target-class-config-does-not-exist)