# Testing: Target class [config] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, юнит-тесты

Нужно протестировать функционал входа в админку и создания товара.
Вышло так:

```
public function testExample() {
    $user = User::find(1);

    $this->post(route('login'), [
        'email' => 'admin@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'ghsgdsfgfg',
    ]);
    $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);

    $this->post(route('marks.store'), [
        'name' => 'mark1',
        'alias' => 'mark1'
    ]);
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('marks',['name' => 'mark1']);
}
```

в результате ошибка:

```
PHPUnit 8.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..array:2 [
0 => "admin"
1 => "marks"
]
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Feature\NewTest::testExample
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [config] does not exist.
```

Почему указывает на config ?
1е утверждение срабатывает `assertAuthenticatedAs`, второе нет
Миграция

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('marks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name',30);
        $table->string('alias',30)->nullable();
        $table->boolean('published')->default(true);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```